# RAID array setup - same drives in different arrays

Tags: raid, mdadm

I'm trying to finish configuring and mounting a RAID array on a machine I've become responsible for. I feel the previous owner tried and failed to set up the array, but I don't know how to be sure. My final goal is to set up the 10TB array. I *think* that array is `md126` or `/dev/md/Volume1_0`.

I've never set up a RAID array before. I've copied the commands from the various guides that I've followed below. I can't work out how there are 2 (or 3?) RAID arrays, and I can't work out how to (or if I should) add a file system to `Volume1_0`.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

```
root@mycompubnt01:/home/mycompmarine# cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 metadata=imsm UUID=95741e7f:d82f8bf3:4aefbd16:5e39c59e
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume1_0 container=/dev/md/imsm0 member=1 UUID=4c0ab41a:33ae8cfc:1223a9ff:b4d278d5
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume0_0 container=/dev/md/imsm0 member=0 UUID=e7b25684:e271d6ec:d874c72c:d636b3aa
MAILADDR root
```

```
root@mycompubnt01:/home/mycompmarine# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid10] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md125 : active raid10 sda[3] sdb[2] sdc[1] sdd[0]
      104857600 blocks super external:/md127/0 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      
md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid10 sda[3] sdb[2] sdc[1] sdd[0]
      11035360256 blocks super external:/md127/1 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      
md127 : inactive sdc[3](S) sdd[2](S) sda[1](S) sdb[0](S)
      20804 blocks super external:imsm
       
unused devices: <none>
```

```
root@mycompubnt01:/home/mycompmarine# lsblk -f
NAME      FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/aws-cli/291
loop1     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/aws-cli/293
loop2     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop3     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/core20/1891
loop4     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/core20/1974
loop5     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/core22/750
loop6     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/core22/817
loop7     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/firefox/2908
loop8     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop9     squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop10    squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/lxd/24322
loop11    squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/snapd/19361
loop12    squash 4.0                                                      0   100% /snap/snapd/19457
sda       isw_ra 1.3.0                                                             
├─sda1                                                                             
├─sda2                                                                             
├─sda3                                                                             
├─md125                                                                            
│ ├─md125p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       D7FC-D657                                   1G     1% /boot/efi
│ ├─md125p2
│ │       ext4   1.0         5d7eaaf1-3134-4d19-a65b-ee941a989946      1.4G    20% /boot
│ └─md125p3
│         LVM2_m LVM2        CtAGB4-n1QZ-xhHA-CFLQ-sRNN-UhM8-PH6vJV                
│   └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
│         ext4   1.0         3ec3a532-68f2-4421-bb80-f910e2bcc3b7     16.8G    59% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                                                                  /
├─md126                                                                            
│ ├─md126p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       0316-DC74                                             
│ └─md126p2
│         ext4   1.0         dbb81a20-ad2e-4443-b386-761961fc3fa8                  
└─md127                                                                            
sdb       isw_ra 1.3.0                                                             
├─sdb1                                                                             
├─sdb2                                                                             
├─sdb3                                                                             
├─md125                                                                            
│ ├─md125p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       D7FC-D657                                   1G     1% /boot/efi
│ ├─md125p2
│ │       ext4   1.0         5d7eaaf1-3134-4d19-a65b-ee941a989946      1.4G    20% /boot
│ └─md125p3
│         LVM2_m LVM2        CtAGB4-n1QZ-xhHA-CFLQ-sRNN-UhM8-PH6vJV                
│   └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
│         ext4   1.0         3ec3a532-68f2-4421-bb80-f910e2bcc3b7     16.8G    59% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                                                                  /
├─md126                                                                            
│ ├─md126p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       0316-DC74                                             
│ └─md126pa
│         ext4   1.0         dbb81a20-ad2e-4443-b386-761961fc3fa8                  
└─md127                                                                            
sdc       isw_ra 1.3.0                                                             
├─md125                                                                            
│ ├─md125p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       D7FC-D657                                   1G     1% /boot/efi
│ ├─md125p2
│ │       ext4   1.0         5d7eaaf1-3134-4d19-a65b-ee941a989946      1.4G    20% /boot
│ └─md125p3
│         LVM2_m LVM2        CtAGB4-n1QZ-xhHA-CFLQ-sRNN-UhM8-PH6vJV                
│   └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
│         ext4   1.0         3ec3a532-68f2-4421-bb80-f910e2bcc3b7     16.9G    59% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                                                                  /
├─md126                                                                            
│ ├─md126p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       0316-DC74                                             
│ └─md126p2
│         ext4   1.0         dbb81a20-ad2e-4443-b386-761961fc3fa8                  
└─md127                                                                            
sdd       isw_ra 1.3.0                                                             
├─md125                                                                            
│ ├─md125p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       D7FC-D657                                   1G     1% /boot/efi
│ ├─md125p2
│ │       ext4   1.0         5d7eaaf1-3134-4d19-a65b-ee941a989946      1.4G    20% /boot
│ └─md125p3
│         LVM2_m LVM2        CtAGB4-n1QZ-xhHA-CFLQ-sRNN-UhM8-PH6vJV                
│   └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
│         ext4   1.0         3ec3a532-68f2-4421-bb80-f910e2bcc3b7     16.8G    59% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                                                                  /
├─md126                                                                            
│ ├─md126p1
│ │       vfat   FAT32       0316-DC74                                             
│ └─md126p2
│         ext4   1.0         dbb81a20-ad2e-4443-b386-761961fc3fa8                  
└─md127
```

```
root@mycompubnt01:/home/mycompmarine# mkfs.ext4 -L md_Volume1 /dev/md/Volume1_0
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Found a gpt partition table in /dev/md/Volume1_0
Proceed anyway? (y,N) n
```

I'm running Ubuntu 22:04

Comment: If this help, the directory `/dev/md` just creates links to `/dev/md*` devices.  To make sure you are on the correct device, you can do an `ls -l /dev/md` and see what `Volume1_0` points to.

Comment: Thank you. The answer in the end was that the devices were all properly configured as RAID, but the partitions were not correctly configured. It was a simple fix with LVM.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question with the steps needed for the fix and marking it as resolved so other with a similar issue have something to try should they run into a similar problem.